# How to stop JDBC databases in Mule generating .dat files?

Tags: jdbc, datasource, mule, mule-studio

I followed the example by referring http://blogs.mulesoft.org/working-with-databases-jdbc-in-mule-studio/.

It worked out well but I have a query. A series of .dat files are getting generated. How to stop that?

Answer (score 0):

That is an expected behavior when you run a Mule example that outputs files, as it is the default file extension used by Mule file transport. If you want to run the example without the file output, and see the output in the MuleStudio Console tab instead, replace `<file:outbound-endpoint path="/Users/myUser/myFolder" doc:name="File"/>` with `<logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]"/>`